# AngularJS: Should I observe optional attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Assume I have a directive `my-button` with an optional attribute `disabled`. People could use this directive like:

```
<my-button>Button text</my-button>
```

or

```
<my-button disabled="variable">Button Text</my-button>
```

Should I be *watching* for a `disabled` attribute? Could these usages somehow transition from one to the other?

---

In response to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s request for the code in question, here's a clean version of the directive function:

```
function ButtonDirective() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            click: '&',
            disabled: '=?',
        },

        template: '<a class="my-button" ' +
            'data-ng-class="{\'my-button-disabled\': disabled}" ' +
            'data-ng-click="disabled || click()" ng-transclude />',
        transclude: true
    };

    function link(scope) {
        if (typeof scope.disabled == 'undefined') scope.disabled = false;
    }

    return directive;
}
```

The directive creates an anchor tag styled as a button. It accepts two properties/parameters: click and disabled. The latter is optional. When disabled, the click event should fire when clicked, otherwise the the click event should fire when clicked.

To reiterate: Should I worry about someone somehow adding, removing, or modifying the disabled attribute after the fact? If so, how should I go about it?

Comment: It depends on how you implement the directive, and on what it's supposed to do. Post the code, and tell us what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hashing things out with [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), he counseled me to not worry about the HTML attribute changing.